# Caesar Cipher → Bzdrzq Bhogdq

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

I wrote this [Caesar cipher and decipher](http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/caesar-cipher/) just for the sake of practising OOP (previous answers to my [java](/questions/tagged/java) questions all seem to point to OOPness).

What it is:

> The Caesar cipher is one of the earliest known and simplest ciphers.
>   It is a type of substitution cipher in which each letter in the
>   plaintext is 'shifted' a certain number of places down the alphabet.

Currently I have a `Cipher` interface and a `CaesarCipher` class: I am planning to add a [Vigenère Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) soon.

Code:

**Cipher.java**

```
public interface Cipher {

    public String cipher(String text);

    public String decipher(String cipherText);

    public char getCipheredChar(char textChar);

    public char getDecipheredChar(char cipherChar);

}
```

**CaesarCipher.java**

```
public class CaesarCipher implements Cipher {

    private static final int LETTERS = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;

    private int shift;

    public CaesarCipher(int shift) {
        if (shift < -LETTERS || shift > LETTERS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value of shift: " + shift
                    + " is invalid.");
        }
        this.shift = shift;
    }

    public int getShift() {
        return shift;
    }

    @Override
    public String cipher(String text) {
        char[] result = text.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = getCipheredChar(result[i]);
        }
        return new String(result);
    }

    @Override
    public String decipher(String cipherText) {
        this.shift = -shift;
        String result = cipher(cipherText);
        this.shift = -shift;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public char getCipheredChar(char textChar) {
        if (textChar > 'A' && textChar < 'z') {
            char result = (char) (textChar + shift);
            char compare = Character.isUpperCase(textChar) ? 'Z' : 'z';
            char lowCompare = Character.isUpperCase(textChar) ? 'A' : 'a';
            return (char) (result > compare ? result - 26
                    : (result < lowCompare ? result + 26 : result));
        }
        return textChar;
    }

    @Override
    public char getDecipheredChar(char cipherChar) {
        this.shift = -shift;
        char result = getCipheredChar(cipherChar);
        this.shift = -shift;
        return result;
    }

}
```

And tests!

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCipher {

    @Test
    public void testShift1() {
        CaesarCipher cipher = new CaesarCipher(1);
        assertEquals("AaBbCc", cipher.decipher("BbCcDd"));
        assertEquals("Bzdrzq", cipher.decipher("Caesar"));
        assertEquals("Bzdrzq Bhogdq...", cipher.decipher("Caesar Cipher..."));
    }

    @Test
    public void testShift5() {
        CaesarCipher cipher = new CaesarCipher(5);
        assertEquals("AaBbCc", cipher.decipher("FfGgHh"));
        assertEquals("Xvznvm", cipher.decipher("Caesar"));
        assertEquals("Xvznvm Xdkczm...", cipher.decipher("Caesar Cipher..."));
    }

}
```

Concerns:

1. Are my tests fine?
2. Is my OOP structure good?
3. And as usual, anything else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A few comments about your `Cipher` interface:

- A cipher is an algorithm to encrypt something, so your `cipher` method should be renamed to `encrypt`. To match `encrypt`, you should change `decipher` to `decrypt`.
- `getCipherChar` and `getDecipheredChar` is only really applicable to a few ciphers and not to a general cipher. For example, in the Viginere cipher, the encrypted character depends on the relative position compared to the repeated key. Therefore you can't tell what the result will be without additional information regarding where it is in the string. Other algorithms are more complex. These methods can still be used internally in `CeasarCipher`, but should be removed from the `Cipher` interface.

Regarding `CeasarCipher`:

- Chars aren't just A-Z and a-z, and the Cipher interface is a guarantee that you will encrypt/decrypt an arbitrary string. Currently any other character stays the same, which is not what the Ceasar cipher is. Therefore you should change your code to just increment a char's value by the shift, modulo `Character.MAX_VALUE`, with some care as a negative shift could lead to a negative modulo which can be fixed by calculating the final char as described in the following code:

---

```
char shiftedChar(char c, int shift):
    int ROLLOVER = Character.MAX_VALUE;
    return (((c + shift) % ROLLOVER) + ROLLOVER) % ROLLOVER;
```

Alternatively you could specify some sort of `Alphabet` type (which should be something like a `List<Character>`) which restricts the subset of `Character`'s that you are interested in.

Comment: Why use "encrypt" when it would make more sense to name it "encipher"?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I've rarely heard people say encipher while encrypt/decrypt is quite common. In any case, as long as its not just "cipher", which isn't even a verb it's fine.

Comment: perhaps it's just location differences, then. Where I am, encipher is quite common.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I have to agree with mleyfman on this one. This might be nit picking, but code should be as universal as much as possible, if we start localizing all the internals of a code base too much, it'll make it difficult for future consumers/users of the code who aren't local. My home language is Afrikaans, but if I start naming all my variables in Afrikaans it would make it impossible for more than 90% of the world to read (easily)

Answer (score 16):

I don't recommend temporarily overwriting an instance variable like this:

> ```
> @Override
> public String decipher(String cipherText) {
>     this.shift = -shift;
>     String result = cipher(cipherText);
>     this.shift = -shift;
>     return result;
> }
> ```

If an exception occurs in `cipher()`, then not only would you have that problem to deal with, but also another mysterious bug as a side-effect.  Furthermore, this temporary change makes code that would otherwise be threadsafe become un-threadsafe.

Suggested alternative:

```
public String decipher(String cipherText) {
    return new CaesarCipher(-this.shift).encipher(cipherText);
}
```

Comment: It's safer if a private `getCipheredChar` function is created that takes the shift as a parameter and both public `cipher` and `decipher` forward to that.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding tests, always try to come up with crazy input. What happens if we try `cipher(null)`, `cipher("")` or `cipher("#%(/¤=")`?

Some of these inputs do not make sense in your cipher, but are not handled either.